# Was Doc Brown ever blamed for the clock tower?

Tags: back-to-the-future

Towards the end of BTTF, we see Doc Brown be approached by a police officer. Doc explains that he's doing a *weather experiment* as he's wiring up the two light posts. Later that night the clock tower gets struck by lightning and stops working.

**Was Doc ever blamed for or suspected of breaking the clock?**

There's a least one witness who saw him (a cop to boot) in the area doing something for science, and then all of a sudden, ZAP, no more clock. Seems like he'd be the first suspect if anyone started investigating. Was this ever addressed?

Comment: Well, he did have a **Permit** for the experiment. More importantly, what was the **Weather Experiment Permit** that he pulled out of his wallet and gave to the cop? A five-dollar bill? If he did pay the cop to look the other way, the cop would not have ratted him out.

Comment: you seem to be asserting that some city official could be made to believe that Doc's experiment somehow *caused* the lightning storm or that it caused the lightning to strike at that particular location. Try as I might, I can't imagine a situation in which someone would believe such a thing.

Comment: @PaulL It's a known fact that lightning rods attract lightning (hence the name). While they couldn't prove that Doc *caused* the storm, they *would* have a reasonable assumption (especially for the 50s and their fear for all things kooky), that Doc's experiment may have very well forced the lightning to strike the tower the night of the storm.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd did Doc put a lightning rod atop the clock tower?  I honestly don't remember that - I thought he connected the cable to a metal structure that was already part of the tower.  If he did indeed put the rod there, then I agree with you and I retract my comment.

Comment: @HannoverFist Since we're not shown what type of *permit* he gives the cop, we can't automatically assume he paid him off. Knowing Doc, he could have very well wrote up a very convincing forgery of the needed paperwork.

Comment: @PaulL I'm not sure if he put the rod there himself, but his experiment could be perceived as the source of the damage. Again, think with a 1950's mentality.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd the deleted scene from that part of the film depicts Brown paying off (clearly with cash) the cop, who then asks, “You’re...not gonna set anything on fire this time are you, Emmet?” To which Doc replies “nah” with a grin as the officer walks on. It also suggests people in Hill Valley know Doc’s a crazy inventor who pulls crazy stunt tests with his inventions and apparently caused a small fire the last time.

Comment: I’ve always wondered this also. I would think that Doc would need to remove his equipment and leave quickly. But then in the sequel, Marty re-appears, and Doc faints. And in the next sequel, we learn Marty drove him home, apparently unconscious. Marty doesn’t seem the type to think ahead or to tidy messes.

Answer (score 2):

As a result of Doc's "experiment", the clock tower was saved in altered 1985. The lightning struck the wire and was drained into DeLorean's flux capacitor. Marty finds this out arriving to the timeline where his father is a successful writer and Lorraine is no longer a fat drunk.

Comment: What's the source for this?

Comment: The movie. In 1985, after safe return from 1955, Marty finds the clock tower undamaged.

Comment: How can you tell? We only see it for a few seconds at night, with no real comparison from earlier in the movie.

Comment: There's nothing in the novel about the clock being fixed. Also, the clock's hands are set to the same time they froze at before.

Comment: I thought I remembered this as well, that by Doc sending Marty back, it prevented the Clock from being destroyed. Doesn't the Save The Clocktower handout change or something?

Comment: @Broklynite I'm gonna need a source for this

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I've looked but can't find a copy to watch to confirm so I'm going to go with it being my imagination. Because I also remember a throwaway from the second movie with someone doing something similar to the first movie and trying to get it repaired and it still isn't. So my memory is clearly wonky.

Comment: No. When Marty returns to 1985 at the end of the first movie, the clock tower is still stuck on 10:04 (his arrival time is 1:25 AM). Also in 2015, they’re still raising money to fix the clocktower.